# SQL Query to get Percentage of Elapsed Time calculating total time and time to next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL table like this (with variable count of rows returned):

```
TimeStamp               State

2015-04-27 09:49:14.567 SETUP
2015-04-27 10:10:07.340 EXECUTING
2015-04-27 14:15:12.017 WAITING
2015-04-27 14:15:48.263 EXECUTING
2015-04-27 14:29:10.773 WAITING
2015-04-27 14:29:38.177 EXECUTING
2015-04-28 01:58:54.340 WAITING
2015-04-28 02:03:25.257 CLOSED
```

now i need a query to calculate each time stamps percentage start and end as this (actual values are only symbolic):

```
TimeStamp               State         PercentageStart PercentageEnd

2015-04-27 09:49:14.567 SETUP         0               8
2015-04-27 10:10:07.340 EXECUTING     8               20
2015-04-27 14:15:12.017 WAITING       20              26
2015-04-27 14:15:48.263 EXECUTING     26              28
2015-04-27 14:29:10.773 WAITING       28              30
2015-04-27 14:29:38.177 EXECUTING     30              90
2015-04-28 01:58:54.340 WAITING       90              100
2015-04-28 02:03:25.257 CLOSED        100             NULL
```

So Time between first and last TimeStamp record is 100%.
I guess I need a pointer or something, but not sure :/

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2016, yes Girgios Query works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
;WITH CTE_DIFF AS (
   SELECT [TimeStamp], [State], 
          DATEDIFF ( second , 
                    [TimeStamp] , 
                    LEAD([TimeStamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp])) AS time_diff 
   FROM mytable
), CTE_PERC AS (
   SELECT [TimeStamp], [State], time_diff ,
          SUM(time_diff) OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) * 1.0 / 
          SUM(time_diff) OVER () * 100 AS perc
   FROM CTE_DIFF
)
SELECT [TimeStamp], [State], 
       COALESCE(LAG(perc) OVER (ORDER BY [TimeStamp]), 0) AS PercentageStart,
       perc AS PercentageEnd
FROM CTE_PERC
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/FDEJ27730)

Comment: Bro, seriously? Within 7 Minutes! Will you marry me! :) Works like a charm!

Comment: Giorgos, I have a add on which i forgot, how could i get the SUM(Percentage) for the [States] (e.g. so i would get 3 lines: SETUP 3%, EXECUTING 19%, WAITING 78%)

Comment: @TomSchindler No, don't do this, instead consider asking a new question.  You can list this query if needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table ([TimeStamp] datetime, [State] varchar(32));
insert into @t values 
  ('2015-04-27T09:49:14.567','SETUP'),
  ('2015-04-27T10:10:07.340','EXECUTING'),
  ('2015-04-27T14:15:12.017','WAITING'),
  ('2015-04-27T14:15:48.263','EXECUTING'),
  ('2015-04-27T14:29:10.773','WAITING'),
  ('2015-04-27T14:29:38.177','EXECUTING'),
  ('2015-04-28T01:58:54.340','WAITING'),
  ('2015-04-28T02:03:25.257','CLOSED')

Select firstTS, startts, endts, duration,
   100 * Datediff(second, firstTS, startts) / duration startPcnt,
   100 * Datediff(second, firstTS, endts)  / duration  endPcnt
From (Select s.timestamp startts, s.state, e.timestamp endts,
    (Select Min(timestamp) from @t) firstTS,
    (Select cast(DateDiff(second, Min(timestamp), Max(timestamp)) as float) from @t) duration
From @t s join @t e
    on e.timestamp =
       (Select Min(timestamp) from @t
        where timestamp > s.timestamp))x
```

Comment: This is a nice option for those versions of SQL Server which don't support the `LEAD/LAG` analytic functions.

Comment: `'sec' is not a recognized datediff option.`  -- and [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: @SQLZim, thanks, I can never keep those tokens straight. fixed it.

Comment: Also getting an error trying to test the code here: http://rextester.com/PERT98354

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles!